# tapku calendar color

Tags: colors, calendar, ios-simulator, tapku

I am using a TapkuMonthCalendarViewController in my application and when the calendar loads the color scheme of the calendar is not appearing normal on the simulator. Anyone else experience this?

I haven't messed with trying to set the background of anything and I have used this calendar before in other applications and it has never acted like this.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

This is the calendar view i see https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJlaI.png

EDIT: I realized I forgot to include the bundle into my project!  So this is the solution for all future tapku users.

Comment: This happened to me: I forgot to include the bundle into my project. Coincidentally, it looked fine in the simulator; it looked identical to your screenshot above on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You change calendar background than you can change the Calendar tile image .

OR You put this code on drawRect Method.

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect 

{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    //UIImage *tile = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Date Tile.png")];

    CGRect r = CGRectMake(0, 0, 46, 44);
    //CGContextDrawTiledImage(context, r, tile.CGImage);

    if(today > 0){
        int pre = firstOfPrev > 0 ? lastOfPrev - firstOfPrev + 1 : 0;
        int index = today +  pre-1;
        CGRect r =[self rectForCellAtIndex:index];
        r.origin.y -= 7;
        //[[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"TapkuLibrary.bundle/Images/calendar/Month Calendar Today Tile.png")] drawInRect:r];
    }
}
```